# Cytoscape.js - Highlight all paths from the selected node

Tags: javascript, highlight, cytoscape

Here I tried to highlight all paths from the selected node but It dose not work with the bfs Algorithm, who can I solve this ?

I want to highlight all the paths and nodes from the selected node.

[image]

```
        cy.on('click', 'node', function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var bfs = cy.elements().bfs(target, function(){}, true);
        var i = 0;
        var highlightNextEle = function(){
            if( i < bfs.path.length ){
                bfs.path[i].addClass('highlighted');

                console.log(bfs.path[i]);
                i++;
                setTimeout(highlightNextEle, 50);
            }
        };
        highlightNextEle();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution: without any algorithm

`event.target.successors()` - is all I need here

```
        cy.on('click', 'node', function (event) {
        var connectedEdges = event.target.successors()
        var i = 0;

        var highlightNextEle = function(){
            if( i < connectedEdges.length ){
                connectedEdges[i].addClass('highlighted');
                i++;
                highlightNextEle();
            }
        };
        highlightNextEle();
    });
```

[image]